# PHP merge multidimensional array into one

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to amend the following array:

```
Array
(
    [category_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21
            [1] => 22
        )

    [amount] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10000
            [1] => 2000
        )

)
```

I need to get the output to look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 21
            [amount] => 10000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 22
            [amount] => 2000
        )

)
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: It's basic array manipulation. Did you try something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -

```
$array = array
(
    'category_id' => array
        (
            '0' => 21,
            '1' => 22
        ),

    'amount' => array
        (
            '0' => 10000,
            '1' => 2000
        )

);

$new = array();

$keys = array_keys($array);
$elements = 2;

for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    $temp = array_column($array, $i);
    $new[] = array_combine($keys, $temp);
}

var_dump($new);
```

**Output**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["category_id"]=>
    int(21)
    ["amount"]=>
    int(10000)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["category_id"]=>
    int(22)
    ["amount"]=>
    int(2000)
  }
}
```

**[array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)** supported **PHP >= 5.5**

[array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

[Fiddle](https://eval.in/536739)